# oscommerce $php_self returns incorrect value

Tags: php, mysql, oscommerce

osCommerce in their Changelog for version 2.3.4 indicate they handled a problem concerning their variable $PHP_SELF which appears in 11 files. Making that fix has caused a problem for me. I am setting up a new website on my development computer and was going to use oscommerce 2.3.3. When I installed it, it worked without a hitch. I then decided perhaps I should use 2.3.4. I completely deleted the oscommerce catalog directory and database and made a fresh start. After installing 2.3.4, I was not able to log into the admin side. I bypassed the login process and then noticed that none of the text found in language files was appearing.

I discovered an issue with the code near line 42 in admin/includes/application_top.php which sets a value for a variable called $PHP_SELF. $PHP_SELF is supposed to be the name of the file running the current script, e.g. "index.php". In the case of index.php, the value being set is "dex.php". The code appears to be consistently dropping the first two letters of the file name. Since this variable is used to locate the language file, a good portion of the text on the page is absent -- replaced by the its constant variable name.

Since the code was "fixed" to correct another problem, I don't want to simply return to the previous implementation of this variable. Any ideas?

I suspect this may be a configuration issue, so here is my configuration:
Windows 7 Pro x64 SP1,
Apache 2.2.22,
PHP 5.3.13,
MySQL 5.5.24,
Wampserver x64 2.2.

Comment: post your .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Using php5 try to change $PHP_SELF for $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']